# How to put EditText and Send Button in Fragment's Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-xml

I have an activity with three Fragments. Is there a way to add Chat functionality on one of Fragments. Details mentioned below. Let me know if anything else is required.
XML file of the activity is listed below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    .........
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
......
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment's XML for inflating RecyclerView is listed below:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/messageList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below ="@id/appbar"
 >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

My two Fragments are working fine. For third Fragment, I have attached adapter for listing chat message which is working fine however I am unable to attach Edittext and send button for chat functionality which I believed shall be outside adapter but inside Fragment. Can somebody please advise how this can be achieved? I have lost couple of hours in figuring out how this can be achieved? Thanks in advance for your help.

XML for third Fragment is below. Is there a way to display EditText, Send Button and Chatlist in the same Fragment? Chatlist is not a problem. The real issue is to set EditText and Send Button.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/newMessageContainer"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/newMessage"
    android:focusedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/messageList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_below ="@id/appbar"
android:layout_above="@id/newMessageContainer"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**
See Fragment.java file that I have implemented. I am getting error possibly due to ConstraintLayout

```
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
   container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_cheese_list, container, false);
    setupRecyclerView(rv);
    return rv;
    }

private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new 
    SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
        getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 30)));
}
```

Comment: add your fragment code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code updated. Just design like this your are passing wrong way there is link below where you can learn to code android app and is pretty mainted by developer.

**Set fragment like this and pass layout as I have passed**

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
    public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
myAdapter=new MyAdpter();
}


@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
       container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, parentViewGroup, false);
recyclerView= rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyelerview);
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    return rootView;
        }

    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
        LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new 
        SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
            getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 30)));
    }
```

Please follow this if you are new

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work for me also got button click. And keep button click code on **Fragment** not in recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for responding. Have applied XML that you have suggested in Fragment's XML. Getting error possibly due to ConstraintLayout. Edited post to include Fragment.java as well. Kindly advise what changes shall be made in java file as well. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Thanx mate. Yes indeed this is an answer. The only thing soft keyboard popped up. The same need to close for other fragments. Thanks for your time @A.Tale

Comment: @SukeshSaxena Add  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in your manifest the activity having tab and fragment inflated it

Comment: it worked.One minor issue :  When keyboard used in a fragment, it gets popped up in different fragment too. Can you advise here as well. Thanx for your help so far.